# Removing a UIView on connectionDidFinishLoading

Tags: ios

I create a UIView inside the viewDidLoad event using the following code:

```
 // add a white UIView
        UIView *whiteView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)];
        whiteView.tag = 777;
        whiteView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        [self.view addSubview:whiteView];
```

This displays a white screen (view) to the user. Now, when the connection did finish loading the request I like to remove this view. I use the following code inside the connectionDidFinishLoading.

```
 UIView *whiteView = [self.view viewWithTag:777];

        [whiteView removeFromSuperview];
```

But for some reason the whiteView above is not getting removed and I see the white screen all the time. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Change colour of your subview to redColor. Is it still red after connectionDidFinishLoading hit? Most probably your superview is an empty white view or connectionDidFinishLoading never get called.

Comment: Thanks! The controller.view has one element UIWebView. I add another element the whiteView and it does appear on top of the UIWebView which is okay. I changed the color to red and now I see a big red view. connectionDidFinishLoading is not getting fired for some reason. If I remove the whiteView then it gets fired.

Comment: Make sure that you are calling connectionDidFinishLoading in main thread or try this: dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ /* working with views */ });

Comment: If I do not add my whiteView then connectionDidFinishLoading is fired. I have UIView which contains UIWebView. I dynamically add whiteView as shown above. Once, whiteView is added connectionDidFinishLoading is not fired.